# Introducing node.js layer between UI and AWS services

Tags: node.js, angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-serverless

I am designing a solution on AWS that utilizes Cognito for user management.

I am using this Quick Start as a starting point:

[SAAS QuickStart](https://s3.amazonaws.com/quickstart-reference/saas/identity/cognito/latest/doc/saas-identity-and-isolation-with-cognito-on-the-aws-cloud.pdf)

With one significant change: I plan to make this serverless. So no ECS containers to host the services. I will host my UI on S3.

My one question lies with the 'auth-manager' used in the existing solution, and found on github:

[Auth-Manager using Node.js](https://github.com/aws-quickstart/saas-identity-cognito/tree/master/app/source/auth-manager)

Basically, this layer is used by the UI to facilitate interaction with Cognito. However, I don't see an advantage to doing it this way vs. simply moving these Cognito calls into the front-end web application. Am I missing something? I know that such a Node layer may be advantageous for providing a caching layer but I think I could just utilize Elasticache(Redis)as a service if I needed that.

Am I missing something? If I simply moved this Node auth-manager piece into my S3 static Javascript application, am I losing something?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like its pulling some info from
https://github.com/aws-quickstart/saas-identity-cognito/blob/master/app/source/shared-modules/config-helper/config.js

```
//Configure Environment
const configModule = require('../shared-modules/config-helper/config.js');
var configuration = configModule.configure(process.env.NODE_ENV);
```

which exposes lots of backend AWS account info, which you wouldn't want in a front end app.

Best case seems to run this app on a small ec2 instance instead of faragte because of the massive cost difference, and have your front-end send requests for authorization.